# Search for a string in a sql table with php

Tags: php, html, sql, string

Somewhat new with PHP but I think I'm on the right track. I'm trying to search for a serial number on a sql table. I want a response of the serial # and what column its in. There is 4 columns if that helps (id, 30, 32, 31).

EDIT: sorry for the confusion...when I enter in a serial # 002062008002220 (all serials are 16 digits long). I get a blank page to show up...current table is below

30  32  31
002062008002220 002062008002222 002062008002233

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input id="serials" type="text" name="serials" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "nsmserials");

if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['serials']);
$query = "SELECT 30, 32, 31 FROM  nsmtable WHERE 30 LIKE '%$search%' OR 32 LIKE       '%$search%' OR 31 LIKE '%$search%'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<li><span class='name'><b>{$row['serials']}</b></span></li>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: You're `SELECT` is invalid. you want to `SELECT <cols> FROM nsmtable`

Comment: `SELECT nsmtable` - not the right syntax for SELECT query

Comment: Also you are calling mysql_* methods but creating a mysqli connection.

Comment: ty for the quick responses! I made a change to the description

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
query('//...')->fetchColumn()
```

Comment: And why does this solve the problem of the OP? Just posting some code is not a great answer...

Answer (score 0):

i see you mixing up `$_GET[]` and `$_POST` .. 
Try changing

```
$query = "SELECT nsmtable WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['serials']."%'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT nsmtable WHERE id LIKE '%{$search}%'";
```

you already have the search string already prepared. use that instead of $_POST. And for feature cautions don't mix up `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]`. if you don't remember the method you used, Use `$_REQUEST[]`.

I hope this helps.

**ADDED**
Another look at the query reveals something else wrong. I think what you want to do is

```
"SELECT 30, 32, 31 FROM  nsmtable WHERE 30 LIKE '%$search%' OR 32 LIKE '%$search%' OR 31 LIKE '%$search%'"
```

your query does not match any tuple if ID is not a serial number. And you can add some echo statements to see where your script stops.....

**another Edit** Found another error

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input id="serials" type="text" name="serials" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "nsmserials");

if (!$con) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['serials']);
$query = "SELECT 30, 32, 31 FROM  nsmtable WHERE 30 LIKE '%$search%' OR 32 LIKE '%$search%' OR 31 LIKE '%$search%'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(!$result){
    die( "Error : "+ mysqli_error($con))s;
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<li><span class='name'><b>{$row['serials']}</b></span></li>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

You mixed up mysqli and mysql.... choose one and stick with it!

Comment: I've tried $query = "SELECT nsmtable WHERE id LIKE '%{$search}%'";
I've tried $query = "SELECT <cols> FROM  nsmtable WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['serials']."%'";

Comment: updated my above code...take a look. For some reason I am still getting a blank page

Comment: add this code before while "  
   if(!$result) echo "something";   "
are you sure **002062008002220** in the table?

Comment: column 30 has 002062008002220 / 32  has 002062008002222 / 31 has 002062008002233. These columns are varchar(16)

Answer (score 0):

If unsure of passed form fields are of which type use `$_REQUEST`

this will save u from lot of problems.
in your above problem u are using `GET` for sending data from form (that is the reason it is getting shown in ur url)

in in ur PHP script you are using `POST` method. just verify that and the code should work great.

Comment: so remove the "get" method from the form or remove $_GET and use $_REQUEST?

Comment: @doppis remove `$_GET` and replace with `$_REQUEST`